# Classes with Arrays using other class objects

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I have two completed classes at the moment, the Teacher and Student classes have default definitions.

Right now I am trying to figure out the Classroom and School classes. The Classroom class is supposed to hold a Teacher and an array of 35 Student objects.

The School class is supposed to contain an array of 100 Classroom objects.

How do I do this, I sort of know how to initialize an array in a class but I'm not sure how to achieve this using the objects of another class?

```
class Teacher
{
   private:
     string last;
     string first;
     int gradeLevel;
   public:
     Teacher();
};

Teacher::Teacher()
{
   last = "AAAA";
   first = "BBBB";
   gradeLevel = 0;
}

class Student
{
   private:
      string studLast;
      string studFirst;
   public:
      Student();
};

Student::Student()
{
   studLast = "AAAA";
   studFirst = "BBBB";
}

class Classroom
{

};

class School
{
};
```

Comment: Instead of array you can use vector.

Comment: @user1438832 I need to use an array

Comment: @Alex204: Why would you "need" to use an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do here is create a `Teacher`, just one like you wanted, and then create an array of `Student` objects, which if you didn't know is done like `Student students[35];`. Then to the School object which is just an array of `Classroom` objects. Here is the full code:

```
class Classroom
{
private:
    Teacher teacher;
    Student students[35];
public:
    Classroom();
};

Classroom::Classroom()
{
    ;
}

class School
{
private:
    Classroom classrooms[100];
public:
    School();
};

School::School()
{
    ;
}
```

Note: all of the items in the arrays are initialized when you write something like `Student students[35];`. You can check this by doing `cout << this->stduents[12].studLast << endl;`

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
class Classroom
{
private:
    Teacher t; // create a teacher
    Student s[35]; // create an array of 35 students
...
};

class School
{
private:
    Classroom rooms[100]; // create an array of 100 rooms
...
};
```